# Question with MQL4 programming for Loops and Break

Tags: mql4

I am new to MQL4 and learning codes via there website.
Reading about `break;` code and came to this source-code.

This is the code I am trying to understand.
Please help me understand how the answer of the variables comes to.
Thanks in advance.

```
void OnTick()
{
    int a, b, L, s, S, A, B;      // (---Variable Initializing.---)
    L=1000;                       // (---Value for L is 1000 assigned.---)
    for ( a = 1; a < L / 2; a++ ) // (---Now value of a=1
    {                             /*              and a is smaller then 500
                                         so condition is true
                                            and value of a is 499 Now---)
                                     */

       b = ( L / 2 ) - a;         // (---Now b=1000/2=500-499, So value of b is 1)
       s = a * b;                 // (---Now s=499*1=499---)
       if ( s <= S ) break;       /* (---After using if statement,
                                             s is smaller then or equal to S.
                                         there is no value assigned to "S".
                                         So how the condition gets TRUE.---)
                                     */
       A = a;                     // (---now Value of A is 250---)
       B = b;                     // (---now Value of B is 250---)
       S = s;                     // (---now Value of A is 62500---)
    }
    Comment( "  S= ", S,
             ", A= ", A,
             ", B= ", B
             );
    return;
}
```

### My question is:

How the `if(s<=S)` statement get true and loop break to answer `S=62500, A=250, B=250`?

After removing the `if` statement answer is S=499, A=499, B=1.

Answer (score 2):

### The solution has nothing to do with a value of **`S`**:

There are few things to note:

In a strongly typed language, an MQL4 is a case of, a variable declaration helps the compiler-process to assert the variables native data-type, so as to reserve space enough to hold respective values and to choose the proper instructions to manipulate with the variable's respective content in functions. Thus you explicitly **declare** the respective **type** of value, but not always the initial value ( that is language specific and quite dangerous to let implicit magics take place ): `int`, `double`, `string`, `datetime`, etc., where much safer is to declare and initialise:

```
int a = EMPTY,
    b = EMPTY,
    L = EMPTY,
    S = EMPTY,
    ...
    B = EMPTY;
```

### Next the **`break`**:

The code has some language defined syntactic-structure. The general structure of the **`if`** statement may have a formal structure of:

```
 if( <_aCondition_> )
 {   <_an_If_ed_CodeExecutionBLOCK_> }
 else
 {   <_an_Else_ed_CodeExecutionBLOCK_> }
```

In cases, where `<_aCodeExecutionBLOCK_>` consist of a single statement, as is your case with the **`break;`**, there need not be the enclosing pair of curly braces `{...;}` and the such single statement may follow left "naked" right after the syntactic-structure prefix

```
if( <_aCondition_> )
    break;
```

So was the theory, next comes the answer to your experienced problem - if you remove just the `if( <_aCondition_> )`, leaving the "naked" `break;` left in place, now imperatively being executed right in the first pass of the `for(...){...}`-code-block, the results cannot be but the shown `a = 1; b = ( L / 2 ) - 1; s = a * b;` which you confirm on your own, as the naked `break;` did indeed break the code-block execution flow and jumped immediately from the first few steps of the first loop-run right after the closing **`}`**.

```
void OnTick()
{    ...
     for ( a = 1; a < L / 2; a++ )
     {     b = ( L / 2 ) - a;
           s = a * b;
        /* if ( ... )  // . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . a half-removed if() */
                break; // _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ WILL STILL JUMP
           ...
     }
     Comment( "  S= ", S,
              ", A= ", A,
              ", B= ", B
              );
     return;
}
```

The left naked `break;` simply broke the rest of the logic.

Either remove the complete syntactic-structure `if(...)break;` or experience the effects:

```
void OnTick()
{    ...
     for ( a = 1; a < L / 2; a++ )
     {     ...
           if ( s <= S ) break;
           ...
     }
     Comment( "  S= ", S,
              ", A= ", A,
              ", B= ", B
              );
     return;
}
```